# How to load Service provider only for certain routes - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to load my providers depending on routes.
for example, when my `Ticket` routes loaded, I want to load Ticket's providers.
I there any solution for this scenario?

because I have many providers.

Comment: i think then you should use ```middleware``` instead of ```providers```

Comment: @S.M_Emamian: I am not sure what do you mean by `routes are loaded`.

Comment: why would the service provider need to be something to load dynamically like that, if you don't mind me asking?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit old and not required anymore, however I'd like to give the solution I've been using for a few months.

What I've done is to add some specific middlewares that loaded (or acted as) the required service providers. In there I was binding specific services to interfaces based on some request parameters or user settings.

I came up with this idea because of what I described in the previous paragraph: I needed to bind specific services based on parameters that I couldn't access at service provider time.

I hope this is useful